# Verificação de JSON no JQUERY

Tags: jquery, json

Tenho um chat em ajax em meu website.
Porém, acontece de as vezes as mensagens se duplicarem por motivos não relevantes.
Logo, gostaria de verificar se as mensagens que eu recebo no JSON já existem no chat, se existirem, não mostra-las e se não existirem, mostra-las.
O código que eu tenho é:

```js
var VerificaChat = function(TempoRequest){
      $.ajax({
       url: 'chat_receive.php',
       dataType: 'JSON',
       type: 'POST',
       data: 'type=recebeMsg&lobby=' + $('.lobbyid').val(),
       success: function(data){
        if(data.status === 'success'){
         
          for( var i = 0; i < data.msgs; i++){
           if(data[i]['time'] !== 'ambos'){
                      // AQUI EU GOSTARIA DE VERIFICAR AS MENSAGENS MOSTRADAS NO CHAT, E VER SE A MENSAGEM RECEBIDA NO JSON É IGUAL A QUE APARECE NA TELA DO USUÁRIO.
                      //ABAIXO EU MONTO A MENSAGEM E MOSTRO AOS USUÁRIOS.
                      
                     
           $('#chat_box').append('<div class="msg user_' + data[i]['time'] + '"><span>'+ data[i]['nick'] + ': </span>' + data[i]['contente'] +'</div)'); 
                      
                      
                      
           }else{
                      
           $('#chat_box').append('<div class="msg ambos"><span>'+ data[i]['nick'] + ' </span>' + data[i]['contente'] +'</div)'); 
           }
          }

              });
       
    }
```

```html
<div id="chat_box">

<!--EXEMPLO DE MENSAGEM-->
<div class="msg user_azul"><span>VÍTOR:</span> Oi pessoal</div>

</div>
```

O AJAX tem o seguinte retorno em JSON (o retorno varia de acordo com o número de mensagens novas):

```js
{  
   "0":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45454545454",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "1":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"4",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "2":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"5",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "3":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"45",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "4":{  
      "id_user":"10",
      "contente":"44",
      "time":"azul",
      "nick":"ikeda."
   },
   "status":"success",
   "msgs":5
}
```

Comment: Acho que você  não entendeu. A mensagem, no long polling com ajax, as vezes é retornada 2 vezes, logo é mostrada 2 vezes. Eu quero verificar se essa mensagem já foi mostrada e não mostra-la novamente.

Comment: O que deve ser verificado é o contente e o nick. Se o nick e o contente já existirem iguais no chat ele nao mostra novamente.

Comment: Tipo, eu so quero que não apareça quando são 2 mensagens iguais seguidas, entendeu? Tipo o kra pode digitar a msm mensagem, mas não seguida entendeu?

Comment: É, seria um critério. Mas acho que vc pode fazer melhor: coloque um atributo data-attribute em cada div das mensagens com um identificador único, assim basta verificar por isso se há repetido.

Comment: Mas como eu iria verificar se ja existe?

Comment: Se o identificador é unico, entao cada mensagem vai ter id's diferentes.

Comment: ok, vou ver aqui

Comment: Essa duplicidade vem no JSON. O json vem com as últimas mensagens

Comment: entendi.... vou postar uma resposta onde vc elimina duplicidades baseadas no texto digitado

Comment: ok, vou esperar